# How to check a group of check boxes based on class on Angular?

Tags: jquery, angular

I would like to check a group of check boxes with a specific class on angular.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" [(ngModel)]="check_box.view_all" 
class="chk">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" [(ngModel)]="check_box.add_all" 
class="chk">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" (change)="OnCheckBoxAllChange($event)"
[(ngModel)]="check_box.all" class="chk" id="check_all">
```

Typescript:

```
check_box: any = {};
OnCheckBoxAllChange(eve: any) {
    if (this.check_box.all) {
      this.check_box.view_all = true;
      this.check_box.add_all = true;          
    } else {
      this.check_box.view_all = false;
      this.check_box.add_all = false;          
    }
  }
```

How would I do this with a class, something like in jquery ::

```
if ($('#check_all').is(':checked')) {
    $('.chk').prop('checked', 'checked');
} else {
    $('.chk').removeAttr('checked')
}
```

Comment: your code should be working! what is the error?

Comment: How to do it in angular way rather than jquery?

Comment: `[checked]="your.model"`